# When to use backtracking?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Sometimes I see a problem and I'm not sure whether my first instinct should be to brute force all possible solutions + memoize or try to solve the problem intelligently. For example, this problem:

> Given a positive integer n and you can do operations as follow:
>
> If n is even, replace n with n/2. If n is odd, you can replace n with
>   either n + 1 or n - 1. What is the minimum number of replacements
>   needed for n to become 1?

How does one know not to code something that tries every single option for any given n (for example:  `1 + [func(n+1), func(n-1), func(n/2)].min` instead of looking for a more intelligent solution? How do you know to have that instinct?

Comment: Try considering whether or not the program can be expressed as a series of smaller subproblems. If it can, then the problem is a good candidate for dynamic programming, and you can experiment with trying to construct a recurrence to express this relationship.

Comment: It's often about recognizing patterns and similar problems (like the example of (user3802348). Sometimes you immediately see the DP-nature and can analyze it. Sometimes you feel that a problem is NP-complete as it's very similar to some already known one. Again, analysis needed. So knowing many approaches including their inner-workings (and some problems) is basically the knowledge which helps here.

Comment: This is why the design of other-than-trivial algorithms is hard. Some people spend their lives honing knowledge and intuition to "see" the right way forward. Even then, there's lots of trial and discovery. It's a real skill obtained by practice. And of course aptitude is important, too. On a scale of 1 to 100, the this one is about 2, but it's a start. Keep solving as many problems as possible. @sascha has outlined the basic method: guess either NP-hard or there exists a poly-time algorithm.  If the first, look for a proof, else look for an algorithm. If you're unsuccessful, try the other.

Comment: Sometimes a good way to solve problems is by working it backwards, i.e bottom-up. In this case you begin from 1, and memoize the minimum number of steps required to reach a particular state (values of n). As n is a positive integer it would be searching 1 -> 2 -> 3 or 4.. etc. This way it is guaranteed that the DP algorithm is linear in n.

Comment: Thanks for comments all. Happy to mark as the correct answer. @sascha + Gene  that was particularly insightful-- I'll certainly be on the lookout for comparisons for NP-hard